# Return pairs of points from N 2D points where each two points define a line

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashtable

I have a List of 2D points: (x1, y1), (x2, y2) … (xN, yN) - N 2D points.
Each two points define a 2D line.

Return a list of all unique 2D lines, which you can build using pairs of points from the list.

How can I implement using hash table/map - to keep unique lines (there are infinite lines)

I am trying to find the slope and intercept then point of intersection.

slope = y2 -y1 / x2 - x1
intercept = y1 - slope * x1;

(trying to do this in c++)

Comment: then you keep the slope and intercept as a tuple and store them into a hashset. you don't need hashtable here.

Comment: That's all. I'm not even sure what the question is...

Comment: A (slope, intercept) pair uiquely defines a line. So you can use this pair as a key in your hashtable/map. The value can be a list of the lines which belong to the line. This approach is of O(N) both time and space complexity.

Comment: Note that slope-intersect form is not suitable for vertical lines. Normal form is universal: http://www.solitaryroad.com/c426.html

Comment: For what aspect do you need help? Coding in C++ or getting an efficient algoritthm? Do you have to deal with MANY points, or is that not the problem? Why do you specifically want to use a hash: is that part of a task/specification given to you? Please clarify a bit more what you expect from "us" here.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify language, so I will use python here for the sake of easiness. it will look like a joke to python:

```
import itertools


def slope(p1, p2):
    return (p1[1]-p2[1]) / (p1[0]-p2[0])


def slp_intrcpt(p1, p2):
    """
    return the tuple of slope and intercept
    """
    slp = slope(p1, p2)
    return slp, p1[1] - slp * p1[0]


def uniq_lines(points):
    return set(slp_intrcpt(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(points, 2))
```

since `(slope, intercept)` pair is good enough to determine a line, so i would say that finished your requirement.

if you want to keep track of all pairs that produce the lines, you may

```
import collections

def uniq_lines(points):
    d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [])
    for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(points, 2):
        d[slp_intrcpt(p1, p2)].append((p1, p2))
    return d
```

Comment: @user3412649 then it would require more work. but the principle is the same.